# How do I stop my relative links to stylesheets breaking?

Tags: templating

When I navigate to [home]/news/2014/poster my relative links to stylesheets break. I am using:

```
<link href="css/myStylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

How do I stop these links breaking in this scenario?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The links aren't working because that's a relative URL, from whatever the last "directory"-looking segment in your page's URL is.

To resolve this, you can either make your URLs root-relative:

```
<link href="/css/myStylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Or relative to the site URL:

```
<link href="{{ siteUrl }}css/myStylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

The drawback to root-relative URLs is, it makes your site a little less portable - you'll only be able to install the site in a web root (no subfolders) without having to update all URLs.

If this is a localized site with multiple site URLs, then both solutions could have issues. In that case it might make sense to define your own custom config setting in craft/config/general.php:

```
'baseResourceUrl' => "http://example.com/",
```

Then call glad from your templates instead of `siteUrl`:

```
<link href="{{ craft.config.baseResourceUrl }}css/myStylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Thanks for adding the config settings for localized sites, Brandon. Wasn't quite sure if I encountered problems because me redefining `siteUrl` with `define('CRAFT_SITE_URL', '{siteUrl}en/');` in `en/index.php`. Additional question: is the "new" technique to set `siteUrl` with an array `'siteUrl' => array('de' => 'http://example.com/', 'en' => 'http://example.com/en/')` preferable?

Comment: Thanks Brandon. I thought of the 'baseResourceUrl' option but thought there might be a simpler solution.

Comment: @ChristianSeelbach Yes the new [siteUrl](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#siteUrl) config setting is a better way to define locale-specific URLs than defining CRAFT_SITE_URL constants. With the config setting, Craft will know what an entry’s URL is in all locales, so “Share” links will always be correct, for example.

Comment: @BrandonKelly Not to be a jerk, but there's a typo (`baseReaourceUrl`) in the third code block I can't edit. People like me copy those things and become confused later.

Answer (score 4):

You need to make the url absolute, or relative to the root. The url() function will help you to keep this maintainable.

```
{{ url('assets/build/css/main.css') }}
```

This will prepend the {{ siteUrl }} to the path, so if you move the site later, or are running in a multi environment setup, the path will be updated.

Comment: A word of warning about `url()`: it is subject to whether Craft thinks the server supports index.php redirecting, even if you're only pointing it to a static file. So only use it with static file URLs if you've set the [omitScriptNameInUrls](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#omitScriptNameInUrls) config setting to `true`.